# php laravel register with telegram bot

Tags: php, bots, laravel-5.4, telegram, telegram-bot

I try to create registration system with telegram bot in laravel 5.4 , first I install telegram-bot-sdk on my project then I set webhook and everything works nice, but when I want to grab data from users I don't know how should do it ? Because I can only access to last users updates and I cannot detect which message containt to which user ?

Another problem is that I cannot set functions and actions to button, I can just define them in telegram bot.

These are my problems and I want to know first how can I grab information from different users.

Please help me to solve this problem, I just want to register users with 3 or 4 questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need create unique key for user and send this key to bot on start using deep linking. After user click start, you can get key in getUpdates() from telegram.

I think, that you can done it by create a special action for button (in your webpage) witch create an key and store it in database, after storing redirect to telegram.me/botname?key={value}

and on next step you can get base infrormation like firstname, lastname from telegram.

You can't get information about any user of telegram. User need to wtire to bot first to get any information about user or send to user.